# Sed: Remove line from txt file?

Tags: sed

How can I remove the line "name['todo']['remove'] = 3456" from a text file?

```
[test.txt]
name['myname']['test'] = 12
name['todo']['remove'] = 3456
name['todo']['remove']['inspection'] = 34
```

My current approach is not working as expected. The line is still in my file.

```
sed -i "name\['todo'\]\['remove'\]" test.txt
```

The error message is "sed: -e expression #1, char 2: extra characters after command"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -i "/name\['todo']\['remove'] =/d" test.txt
```

Note that the pattern is wrapped with `/` regex delimiters, and the `d` means the matched line will get removed.

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/6w4r8N):

```sh
s="[test.txt]
name['myname']['test'] = 12
name['todo']['remove'] = 3456
name['todo']['remove']['inspection'] = 34"
sed "/name\['todo']\['remove'] =/d" <<< "$s"
```

yielding

```
[test.txt]
name['myname']['test'] = 12
name['todo']['remove']['inspection'] = 34
```

If you want to make sure you only match a whole line with digits after `=`, you may use `"/^name\['todo']\['remove'] = [0-9]*$/d"` command with `sed`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple `grep -vF` would work fine here that matches using **fixed string** without requiring escaping of special regex characters:

```sh
grep -ivF "name['todo']['remove'] " file

[test.txt]
name['myname']['test'] = 12
name['todo']['remove']['inspection'] = 34
```